# wget trouble, explicit encryption

Tags: ftp, wget

I cant access server with explicit encryption.

Example:

```
wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 --no-proxy --passive-ftp    
ftp://username:password@host:port/folder/file.pdf
```

Response:

> Logging in as username ...
>
> The server refuses login.
>
> Retrying.

Can somebody help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless your username and password are `username` and `password`, the server is going to refuse the login.

Comment: no no its just for privacy.

Answer (score 0):

try the alternate parameter syntax

`--ftp-user`  and `--ftp-password` so therefore:

```
wget --secure-protocol=SSLv3 --no-proxy --passive-ftp --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=password ftp://host:port/folder/file.pdf
```